# ASP DotNet Core 6 MVC save/auto-save partially completed forms

Tags: sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

I have been searching for an answer of how to save and auto-save partially completed forms.  My users need the ablity to save forms to complete at a later time.  My issue is the model and the database tables require specific parts of the data to be complete before it can be saved into the database.

I am not inserting code because it is all standard CRUD that currently works.  A user has to complete the forms (some have been broken into smaller sections because of the size) before they can submit them.

I am just looking for articles and/or tutorials on this subject.  I am think the answer is in ajax, which, unfortunately, I have not had a lot of experience with.  If anyone can point me in the correct direction on this, I would very much appreciate it.

I simply need the user to be able to pull up the form that is associated with a specific user, participant, participant_activity, and form.  A user can be working on multiple participants, who can have multiple activities.  It is a complex app that works but needs the ability to save and autosave (in case a user has to walk away from thier computer for a time).

Any suggestions?  Is more information needed?  Thanks up front for any direction.

Comment: I suggest you save/autosave partially completed form data separately from the main model with constraints. The partial data doesn't necessarily need to in stored in a relational structure, maybe just serialized json.

Comment: But serialized json needs to be stored somewhere doesn't it?  The user may not come back to the form for a day or two.

Comment: The serialized version needs to be stored but not necessarily in normalized form. If you don't have a document store handy (e.g. mongo), you could store the json in an `nvarchar(MAX)` column along with columns like user name, etc. to retrieve the partial forms later.

Comment: You could serialize it and store it in IndexedDb in the client browser using something like the onbeforeunload event, or a "Save for Later" button, instead of the Db since you may not want to fill your Db with incomplete records.
On form load, check the IndexedDb for a saved record to restore/finish or give the user a button.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: sounds like foreign key restraints?  You can create/seed the db with a "none" entry of the object that is required to be set.  Then set that "none" value's UID as the default for the foreign-key.  (You'll still have the table relationship in-tact, and you can check for this UID being set on controllers that use the value... lookup the "none" entry and check against that UID to branch code for "none" behavior.)

Comment: @StevenBitaxi, I think this would not work since our faculty use multiple computers across campus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is just and examply form I was using to figure this out.  I was trying to design something that I can use for all of my forms.  This is a first attempt and gets me what I need.  Please do not trash me.  I was just figuring out how to do this.  I would apprectiate any feedback that would improve this.

My SQL Server table has five fields:

- UserId(PK, int, not null)
- ActivityId(PK, int, not null)
- JsonData(nvarchar(max), not null)
- DateStored(datetime, not null)
- FormName(nvarchar(50), not null)

My Form:

```
@model TestTableVM


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 m-auto">
       <form asp-action="Create" id="createTable" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger">
            <span id="message"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label asp-for="MI" class="form-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MI" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="form-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="AddressLine1" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AddressLine1" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="AddressLine2" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AddressLine2" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <label asp-for="State" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="State" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label asp-for="Zip" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Zip" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="Phone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="HowYouHeard" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="HowYouHeard" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.HowHeard, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                @*<select asp-for="HowYouHeard" class="form-control" id="selectHowHeard"></select>*@
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col-sm-6 m-auto">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">
                            Add  <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button onclick="pushThis" class="btn btn-primary" id="pushThis">
                Save for later <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The scripts in my form:

```
 @section Scripts {
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        //e.returnValue = '';
        alert("Changes you have made are being save....");
        checkRecords(10, 16, "TestTableCreate");
    });


    //let timerId = setInterval(() => checkRecords(10, 16, "TestTableCreate"), 60 * 1000);

    document.getElementById('pushThis').onclick = function () {
        //alert("this worked!");
        var form = $('#createTable');
        var formName = "TestTableCreate";
        var json = form.serialize();
        //alert(json);
        //var json2 = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model));
        // alert(json2);
        var exists = checkRecords(16, 10, formName);
        //if (exists == false) {
        //    alert;
        //}
        //else {
        //    deleteRecord(16, 10);
        //    saveRecord(16, 10);
        //}
    }

    function checkRecords(userId, activityID, formName) {
        var form = $("#createTable");
        var json = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/TestTable/CheckRecord/" + activityID + "/" + userId + "/" + formName,
            success: function (response) {
                //alert("Here " + response.message);
                if (response.message == true) {
                    //alert("Updating");
                    updateRecord(activityID, userId, formName, json);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    //alert("Saving");
                    saveRecord(activityID, userId, formName, json);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    function saveRecord(activityId, userId, formName, json) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/TestTable/Insert/" + activityId + "/" + userId + "/" + formName + "/",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            data: json,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.message);
                alert(response.status + "--" + response.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function deleteRecord(activityId, userId, formName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/TestTable/DeleteRecord/" + activityId + "/" + userId + "/" + formName,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.message);
                alert(response.status + "--" + response.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function updateRecord(activityId, userId, formName, json) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/TestTable/UpdateRecord/" + activityId + "/" + userId + "/" + formName + "/",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            data: json,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert(response.status + "--" + response.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pportal2.data
{
  public class TempFormStorage
  {
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public int? ParticipantActivityId { get; set; }
    public string? FormName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? JsonData { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime? DateStored { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And here are the actions on my controller that the javascript uses to save the data:

```
        // this method will save form data
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[Controller]/[Action]/{id?}/{user?}/{formName?}/{testModel?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Insert(int id, int user, string formName, TestTableVM testModel)
    {
        try 
        {
            TempFormStorage model = new TempFormStorage
            {
                UserId = user,
                ParticipantActivityId = id,
                FormName = formName,
                JsonData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(testModel).ToString(),
                DateStored = DateTime.Now,
            };
            await _ctx.TempFormStorage.AddAsync(model);
            var result = await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

            if(!result)
            {

                return Json(new { Status = "error", Message = "" });
            }
            return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = "Data was saved" });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "error", Message = ex });
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[Controller]/[Action]/{id?}/{user?}/{formName?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CheckRecord(int id, int user, string formName)
    {
        var test = await _ctx.TempFormStorage
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.UserId == 10 && q.ParticipantActivityId == 16 && q.FormName == formName);
        if(test != null)
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = true });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = false });
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[Controller]/[Action]/{id?}/{user?}/{formName?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRecord(int id, int user, string formName)
    {
        var test = await _ctx.TempFormStorage
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.UserId == user && q.ParticipantActivityId == id && q.FormName == formName);

        if(test != null)
        {
            _ctx.TempFormStorage.Remove(test);
            var result = await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
            if (result)
            {
                return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = "Data was removed" });
            }
            return Json(new { Status = "error", Message = "" });
        }
        return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = "No record to delete" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[Controller]/[Action]/{id?}/{user?}/{formName?}/{testModel?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateRecord(int id, int user, string formName, TestTableVM testModel)
    {
        var test = await _ctx.TempFormStorage
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.UserId == user && q.ParticipantActivityId == id && q.FormName == formName);
        if(test != null)
        {
            test.JsonData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(testModel).ToString();
            test.DateStored = DateTime.Now;

            _ctx.TempFormStorage.Update(test);

            var result = await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

            if (result)
            {
                return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = "Data was updated" });
            }
            return Json(new { Status = "error", Message = "There was an issue." });
        }
        return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = "Nothig to update." });
    }
```

Their may be an easier way and a better way, but this is what I have so far and it appears that it does what I need it to.  My next goal is to get the code so that the action does not require a specific model to save the data.  That has been my challenge so far.  Currently the Insert and Update actions are required to be built for each form.  I tried sending the Json data as a string to the action, but cannot seem to get it to do that.  Not sure what I am doing wrong there.  If I could send it as a string, it would not require an action for each form.  Then, it could be a controller that handles saving for any form.

Comment: Regarding your next goal: why didn't you write a Insert or Update method with parameter of type object in a base controller like "public async Task<IActionResult> StoreTempData(object model)" ? A distinct controller is not what you want but a hierarchy should do the job, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

You have to post these partial data to another server database.

I think the database should have 3 columns:
"username" and "URL" and a JsonData to save the partial values.
So when user open a page, you can search by "username" and "url" to read the JsonString.
(Just note that only post "URL" and "JsonData" to backend, you should parse the username from authenitcated identiy)

At front end, the post function can be trigger by button click or idle event. I write some code may help.

```
<form id="myform">
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="age">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="age">
    </p>
    <p>
        <Button type="button" onclick="postUncompleteData" value="save">
        <input type="submit" id="formSave">
    </p>
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    //post to backend
    function postUncompleteData(){
        $.ajax('api/xxx', {      
                    type: 'POST', 
   
                    data: {
                        'url': window.location.href,// you will need to save url to pull form next time 
                        "uncompleteData":{
                          'name': $("#name").val(), // data in form
                          'age': $("#age").val()     // data  in form
                        }

                    },  
                });
    }


    //check idle 
    var LastActiveTime = new Date();
    document.onclick = function() {LastActiveTime = new Date();};      //reset LastActiveTime
    document.onmousemove = function() {LastActiveTime = new Date()};
    document.onkeypress = function() {LastActiveTime = new Date()};

    function CheckIdleTime() {                   //check if idle > 10mins excute post function
        if((parseInt(new Date().getTime()-LastActiveTime.getTime()))>600000){
          postUncompleteData();
        };
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {                       
                myVar = setInterval("CheckIdleTime()", 3000);  //excute checkIdleTime every 10mins
            });




    function InitilizeData(){
        $.ajax('https://localhost:7231/test', {      
                    type: 'Get',  
                    success: function (data) {
                      obj=JSON.parse(data);        //parse string to jsonObject
                      $("#name").val(obj.name);  
                      $("#age").val(obj.age);                  
                }});
    }

    InitilizeData();  //excute initialize on page open.

  </script>
```

A simple backend to get data for test

```
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string test()
        {
            var result = new { name = "tom", age = 12 };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        }
```

-----------------------------------------Original Answer----------------------------------------
You can use LocalStorage of browser. It can save 5MB data and is usually used to save uncomplete forms. Unlike cookie, it is not being send to server on every request.
You can try the following code

```
<form id="myform">
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="Male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="Female">Female
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="phone">Contact Number</label>
      <input type="number" id="phone">
    </p>
 
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option value="USA">USA</option>
      <option value="UK">UK</option>
      <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
      <option value="France">France</option>
    </select>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="formSave">
    </p>
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
        localStorage.setItem("name", $("#name").val());
        localStorage.setItem("phone", $("#phone").val());
        localStorage.setItem("country", $("#country").val());
        //save selected radio
        var k_val = $(":radio[name=sex]:checked").val();
        localStorage.setItem("k_val", k_val);

    }

    //Get Value from LocalStorage
    
    function myStorage() {
    
    var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var phone = localStorage.getItem("phone");
    var province = localStorage.getItem("country");
    //put storage value to input
    $("#name").val(name);
    $("#phone").val(phone);
    $("#province").val(country);
    //radio
    $(":radio").removeAttr("checked");//important
    var kk_val = localStorage.getItem("k_val");; 
    $(':radio').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == kk_val) {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
    })
    }
    
    myStorage();
  </script>
```

Every time the input change, the eventlisener will update LocalStorage, when you refresh, the data will be read and load.
[image]

Comment: But how effective is this if the user walks away for a day or two?

Comment: @ChrisWoodard there is no time limit, it can store forever unless user clear it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it has to be retrievable from any computer they use.  Our faculty most likely will be using computers across our campus.

Comment: @ChrisWoodard I modifed the answer you can see if anything help.

Comment: I have been working on this as well.  This is very similiar to what I have come up with.  I actually created a table in SQL Server with fields UserId, ActivityId, FormName, JsonData that I save to.  Everytime a user opens the form, it checks this table for data.  So that was the route I was going an your updated solution is very similiar.  I am trying to finalize my solution and I will post it here.